# Fetch data from db to select in a for loop with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic table which generates table rows based on the first selected tab to get the number of rows. I am not getting the ajax result in my desired select box.

```js
$("#create").click(function () {
    $("#itinerary tbody").empty();
    var days = parseInt($("#days").val());
    var i = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {

        var strToAdd = '<tr><td>Day ' + i + '</td><td><select name="stay_' + i + '" id="stay_' + i + '" class="form-control"><option>--Select</option><option value="portblair">Port Blair</option><option value="havelock">Havelock</option><option value="neil">Neil</option></select></td><td><input type="text" name="itinary_title_' + i + '" id="itinerary_title_' + i + '" class="form-control"/></td><td><textarea name="itinerary_description_' + i + '" id="itinerary_description_' + i + '" class="form-control input-lg"></textarea></td><td><select class="form-control" name="hotel_list_' + i + '" id="hotel_list_' + i + '"><option> Loading..</option></select></td><td><select class="form-control" name="roomtype_list_' + i + '" id="roomtype_list_' + i + '"><option> Loading..</option></select></td></tr>';
        $("#itinerary").append(strToAdd);
    }
});

var days = parseInt($("#days").val());
var i = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
    $("#stay_" + i).change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'hotel_fetch.php',
            data: 'hotel_location=' + $(this).val(),
            success: function (value) {
                var data = JSON.parse(value);
                $("#hotel_list_" + i).empty();
                $("#hotel_list_" + i).append("<option value=''>--Select--</option>");
                data.forEach(function (type) {
                    $("#hotel_list_" + i).append("<option value=" + type.hotel_id + ">" + type.hotel_name + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 padding-top-10">
    <div class="input-group text-black">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Days: </span>
        <select name="days" id="days" class="form-control">
            <option>--Select</option>
            <option value="3">3 Days</option>
            <option value="4">4 Days</option>
            <option value="5">5 Days</option>
            <option value="6">6 Days</option>
            <option value="7">7 Days</option>
            <option value="8">8 Days</option>
            <option value="9">9 Days</option>
            <option value="10">10 Days</option>
            <option value="11">11 Days</option>
            <option value="12">12 Days</option>
            <option value="13">13 Days</option>
            <option value="14">14 Days</option>
            <option value="15">15 Days</option>
            <option value="16">16 Days</option>
            <option value="17">17 Days</option>
            <option value="18">18 Days</option>
            <option value="19">19 Days</option>
            <option value="20">20 Days</option>
        </select>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-success" name="create" id="create">Create</button>
     </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
    <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="itinerary" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>Stay at</th>
                <th>Itinary Title</th>
                <th>Itinary Description</th>
                <th>Hotel id</th>
                <th>Roomtype id</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are expecting JSON response from the server then you should specify the data type in ajax method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when the success callback runs `i` is probably out of context.  Unless `days` is a significantly high value then your  `for` loop will complete before the first `success` function is run.  This is because ajax calls are asynchronous.

To get around this you could add `async: false,` to your ajax properties.  However, the best option would probably be to put your ajax call into a function which is called from within your `for` loop.

Function -

```
function createSelect(element, hotelNum){
  $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'hotel_fetch.php',
        data: 'hotel_location='+ $(element).val(),                 
        success: function(value){
               var data = JSON.parse(value);
               $("#hotel_list_"+ hotelNum).empty();
               $("#hotel_list_"+ hotelNum).append("<option value=''>--Select--</option>");
             data.forEach(function(type){
                 $("#hotel_list_"+ hotelNum).append("<option value="+type.hotel_id+">"+type.hotel_name+"</option>");
              });
       }
     }); 
}
```

`for` loop -

```
for(i=1;i<=days;i++){
  $("#stay_"+i).change(function(){
     createSelect(this, i);
  });
}
```

Comment: how to  trigger the hotel_list?

Comment: thanka lot @John C for your help but what i did is i didnt used the for loop, i jst added onchange event in dynamic rows to pass this, i from the first loop. and it worked, thanx for your help. :)